# Date.now() and DateTime.now() returns different value in Flutter Client and NodeJS server

Tags: javascript, node.js, flutter, unix-timestamp

I am trying to implement a turn-based counter on my Flutter app with the NodeJS backend.

I am storing the timestamp of **each turn on the server** using Date.now() (which returns a timestamp).

The flow is something like this

1. Player 1 makes a turn on their Flutter device
2. That turn is sent to the server and a **"createdAt" is stored using Date.now()**
3. Player 2 is notified of the turn and receives the "createdAt" variable
4. Cycle continues..

On the flutter device, I am aligning the timer properly by subtracting the stored timestamp from device timestamp

**On server**

`createdAt = Date.now();`

**On user device**

```
var timeDiffer = DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch - createdAt;
var totalTime = totalTimeInSecond - (timeDiffer / 1000).ceil();
 
//createdAt is the timestamp of the previous turn that was stored and retrieved from NodeJS server
```

Now, I don't know how but **I am getting a negative value in timeDiffer**.

I am creating the "createdAt" variable first on the server and then receiving it on the device and subtracting it from DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch.

**The difference that I am getting is around -1000 milliseconds**

How is it possible that the value of createdAt is more than DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch.

Comment: I presume you realize that the clock on your client may not be the same as the clock on your server so there could easily be a 1000ms difference between the two.  Beyond that, it isn't very clear in your question where individual timestamps are recorded (on client or server) so we can't really tell what is happening or exactly what the question is.

Comment: If you really need to do this handling timestamps, you could probably let the whole time tracking responsibility to the backend.

Comment: UNIX timestamps are *seconds*, JavaScript timestamps are *milliseconds*.

Comment: @jfriend00 I am really sorry if the question was not clear. The individual timestamps are recorded on the server then this timestamp is compared to the timer running on the client to adjust for any offset.

Comment: @AleZalazar I would have to use a timer on the client side too for implementing the visual changes

Comment: At least some portion of that 1000ms is the latency comprised of all activity between the instant your server sampled the time and the instant your client sampled the time.

Comment: @phatfingers Latency should increase the difference rather than decrease it. Consider this... The (client 1) makes a turn -> turn gets sent to the server -> time stamp is recorded in the server and stored -> stored timestamp is sent from the server to (client 2). -> (client 2) current timestamp is compared with the stored server timestamp. Shouldn't latency increase this difference?

Comment: @VineetMehra Why are you using a client-generated timestamp at all? What do you need this for?

Comment: @VineetMehra You say "*I am aligning the timer properly by subtracting the stored timestamp from device timestamp*", are you referring to `timeDiffer`? If you know that the clocks are not synchronised and expect a time difference, I don't understand why you expect this time difference to always be positive.

Comment: @VineetMehra Latency has affected the difference, even if it's shifting one negative value to another.  Your problem would most reliably be solved by letting the server generate both timestamps used for comparison.

Comment: I mean timestamp is first recorded on the server and then this server timestamp is subtracted from the client's current timestamp, shouldn't the result always be positive... considering the latency factor?

Answer (score 0):

That is because the date and timezone settings on user device might be unfamiliar

I had a similar situation where my server had the timezone of EU and my device had time zone of Asia/Kolkata

I was able to fix it via changing my server timezone. Which you can achieve via using the moment-timezone node package

`const datetime = moment().tz("Asia/Kolkata")`

Or

you can go to your flutter device settings change date and time to your preferred zone.